# Best Practice - Txt files location in Java EE web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In my Java EE web application I'm using some txt files as templates for sent emails.

What are the best practices or standards about where to put these files (WEB-INF, ...)?

Comment: Isn't storing 'em into database a viable option for you ? I would rather keep 'em out of the webapp structure to avoid a deploy each and every time I have to change an email text.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid database because it would be heavy accessing them ( connection to DB, request ...), the email structure would not be changed so many time at most may be 1 time per year, so I want to know best practices used for this.

Comment: you can use cache for db if the change is not that often.

Comment: heavy ? caching them in application context and binding a reload on a servlet GET would solve any heavy load issue. If it's static data  I guess any folder under web-inf can be good. Even having an external home directory (e.g. /home/username/webappName/resources)  can be a good way. It always depends on how often you're changing them.

Comment: As WEB-INF is protected (with some specific exceptions) it is best to place them there, say under WEB-INF/templates/. Like WEB-INF/jsp for internal JSPs.

Comment: Ok thanx, so I would create a directory under /WEB-INF then caching them in a application scoped bean.

Comment: That seems to be the general gist. Caching is ofcourse an area in itself; one may also cache generated (partial) products.

Comment: I don't know why people are voting questions without leaving a comment to explain their vote ?!!!!

Comment: You could add you comments as answers so I can accept or upvote the convenient for my project case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioned in the comments, but here goes.  [From the J2EE specification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/webapp/configurewebapp.html):

> Accessing Information in WEB-INF
>
> The WEB-INF directory is not part of the public document tree of the
>   application. No file contained in the WEB-INF directory can be served
>   directly to a client by the container. However, the contents of the
>   WEB-INF directory are visible to servlet code using the getResource
>   and getResourceAsStream() method calls on the ServletContext or
>   includes/forwards using the RequestDispatcher. Hence, if the
>   application developer needs access, from servlet code, to application
>   specific configuration information that should not be exposed directly
>   to the Web client, the application developer may place it under this
>   directory.

In plain English, anything in `WEB-INF` is available to your source code via the classpath, but not accessible to the outside world via a web request (without help anyway).  Since it would seem you don't want to serve it publicly, under `WEB-INF` would probably be best.  You can pretty much organize that folder however you want, but typically web-apps will dedicate `WEB-INF/classes/` and `WEB-INF/lib/` for compiled source code and JARs, respectively.